Struct attribute randomly resetting after struct method [c#]
I have an Area struct with a HP attribute that begins at 400; said Area struct has a Hurt() function which decrements the instance's HP and returns true if afterwards HP <= 0.
The problem I'm having is that every time Hurt() is called, the Area instance's HP resets to 400 after the Hurt() method ends.
There are no other lines of code in the project that change an instance's HP other than Area's constructor (I checked with Ctrl F), and the method is referencing its own instance's HP so it can't be a ByRef/ByVal issue. Does anyone know what I could be missing to cause this issue?
The Hurt() function in question
The Area struct entire definition if needed

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and/or error messages need to be included in your question as text, not as pictures of text.  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil. Most likely your issues come from that. Having said this, your struct should probably be a class instead. However without any real code (not images of it) that provide how you're using your Area, we can't help you any further.

when I see this kind of struct usage in .NET code, it usually means that either the author, or whoever taught the author, is/was a C programmer; the difference between class and struct in C# is very different to the difference between class and struct  in C, and the short version here is: "this is not how you use struct in C#"

The short version here is that is almost zero chance that this type makes sense as a struct, and should in fact be a class. It is highly likely that the problem here is that you're merrily mutating a copy of the struct in an ambient stack-local location, which is then simply being discarded. The simplest way to see this would be to access the value from a List<Area>; for example this:
List<Area> areas = ...
foreach (var area in areas)
{
    area.Hurt(42);
    // THIS IS NOT THE ITEM INSIDE THE LIST; it is a separate isolated
    // copy of the struct; we can mutate it here, but this has *no
    // impact* on anything else, and in particular: doesn't impact the
    // copy inside the list
}

As a general guide, most struct types should be readonly, which would prevent you from this kind of mistake, but as I said: more likely, it simply shouldn't be a struct in the first place, but rather: a class.
So my suggested fix:
- struct Area // Represents locations on the map;
+ class Area // Represents locations on the map;


Note: in some cases, the compiler will even spot this kind of error, as shown in this minimal example of what I describe (note the CS1654 line):
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

List<Area> areas = [new(42), new(16)];
Console.WriteLine("first loop");
foreach (var area in areas)
{
    var before = area.Value;
    // area.Value += 2; // CS1654
    area.Add(2);
    Console.WriteLine($"from {before} to {area.Value}");
}
// now see them unchanged
Console.WriteLine("second loop");
foreach (var area in areas)
{
    Console.WriteLine(area.Value);
}

struct Area // BAD: do not copy; should be "class" or "readonly struct"
{
    public Area(int value) => Value = value;
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public void Add(int value) => Value += value;
}

which outputs:
first loop
from 42 to 44
from 16 to 18
second loop
42
16


I won't look at pictures of code (i prefer them as a code-formatted text block in the question), but if it is true when you said that "There are no other lines of code in the project that change an instance's HP other than Area's constructor", then the only conclusion is:
The Area instance's HP has not been reset. Obviously that must be the case if we believe your aforementioned claim to be true, unless we start believing in magic or in your computer being an evil entity intend on sabotaging your efforts.
Rather, i suspect, for some reason or another, that when you try obtaining/inspecting the HP value, you use another (freshly) created Area instance whose Hurt method you did not call. In other words, there are at least two Area instances alive in your program, one whose Hurt method has been called, and one whose (unaltered) HP values is obtained from.  That's the issue you need to locate and fix. (Again, assuming your claims in your question hold true.)

"when you try obtaining/inspecting the HP value, you use another (freshly) created Area instance whose Hurt method you did not call." - aka "by-value semantics", aka struct; what OP describes is basically exactly what we should expect to see when using a struct type inappropriately
